# I have tried to login to facebook via curl,

Tags: php, facebook, curl, cookies

I have successfully logged into facebook in this manner but cannot seem to keep the facebook logged in as soon as you click anything in facebook it redirects you to the login page.

I pondered this + thought that it was due to the fact that curl was using the cookie + not the browser, thus when you click you are un - authenticated.

is there any way of setting the cookie file that the curl has exported into the browser?

I was hoping I could simply open the php file + it would curl log me in + then redirect me to my facebook page, thanks for the help here is the code:

```
<?php
  // script name: login_to_facebook.php
  // coder: Sony AK Knowledge Center - www.sony-ak.com

  // your facebook credentials
  $username = "xxxxx";
  $password = "xxxxx";

  // access to facebook home page (to get the cookies)
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.facebook.com");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd() . '/cookies_facebook.cookie');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
  $curlData = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);

  // do get some parameters for login to facebook
  $charsetTest = substr($curlData, strpos($curlData, "name=\"charset_test\""));
  $charsetTest = substr($charsetTest, strpos($charsetTest, "value=") + 7);
  $charsetTest = substr($charsetTest, 0, strpos($charsetTest, "\""));

  $locale = substr($curlData, strpos($curlData, "name=\"locale\""));
  $locale = substr($locale, strpos($locale, "value=") + 7);
  $locale = substr($locale, 0, strpos($locale, "\""));

  $lsd = substr($curlData, strpos($curlData, "name=\"locale\""));
  $lsd = substr($lsd, strpos($lsd, "value=") + 7);
  $lsd = substr($lsd, 0, strpos($lsd, "\""));

  // do login to facebook
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "charset_test=" . $charsetTest . "&locale=" . $locale . "&non_com_login=&email=" . $username . "&pass=" . $password . "&charset_test=" . $charsetTest . "&lsd=" . $lsd);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, getcwd() . '/cookies_facebook.cookie');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, getcwd() . '/cookies_facebook.cookie');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
  $curlData = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);

  echo $curlData;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about setting a cookie for a domain you don't control, which just isn't possible.

Comment: on this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121280/how-to-let-curl-use-same-cookie-as-the-browser-from-php

Daff said that is sent in the HTTP request header, 

I thought that by fathering the cookies_facebook.cookie + placing it into a string + then placing it into that format..

It might work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895955/gmail-facebook-without-username-password-php-login-header-problem

this supports me in the case that properly made curl might work?

Comment: Peter is right. The second link you provided can never work. It involves violating security policies. The first link's answer deems the task impossible.

Comment: It won't work, dude.  This has been a basic tenet of the browser security model for about as long as browsers have existed. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: I agree completely, my wounder was.. this is my cookie that is a valid facebook cookie + its stored in a file via curl, surely it couldent be placed into the browser via javascript- it would still be valid?

I'm happy for everyones help thankyou all

Comment: If you *could* manage to store that cookie with javascript, then yes, this approach would work.  But you can't, so just abandon this idea.