# CURL w/ Cookies - website log in

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I am trying to use CURL to login to a website that uses cookies. The way I am testing the CURLs scripts functionality is as follows:

I am logging in to the site manually through my browser and using a development tool to look at the POST data and cookie information and I'm pasting the information into my curl script.

Once the post/cookie information is set up in my CURL script, I log out of the website on the browser, in order to test if my curl script successfully logs in on its own.

When I do this, I believe the cookie/session provided to my script gets destroyed / becomes inactive.

As a result, after logging out of the website, when I try to log in with my curl script only, I get an error saying `You have been logged out due to inactivity`.

The reason I am getting this error being, because the cookie information provided in the curl script has become outdated / destroyed since I logged out.

Right now, after every time I log out, I must manually log in to the site w/ my browser and paste 'up to date' post / cookie strings into to my Curl script. This is the step I am trying to automate somehow or skip altogether, if possible.

So the question is, is it possible to create a CURL script that successfully logs in to a website using newly generated cookie / post information every time the script is ran?

I appreciate any suggestions, thanks in advance!

```
    $ch = curl_init();

$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';
$url = 'https://www.site.com/Account/Login.aspx?timeout=yes&ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fDefault.aspx';
$login_post = 'lbErrorMsg=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbErrorMsg&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwULLTEyMzc5OTc1NjYPZBYCZg9kFgICAw9kFgYCAw9kFgYCAQ8PFgIeCEltYWdlVXJsBSl%2BL0ltYWdlcy9lbi11cy9193YW5nSW52ZXN0LmdpZmRkAgcPDxYCHgRUZXh0ZWRkAgkPDxYCHwEFH1NhdHVyZGF5IDA0LzA1LzIwMTQgMDg6MjkgUE0gRVRkZAIFD2QWAgICDw8WAh8BZWRkAgkPZBYMZg8WBB4EaHJlZgURL0hlbHAvRkFRLmFzcHgjMDIeBWNsYXNzBQl3YW5nU0lQQzJkAgEPFgIfAgUOL0hlbHAvU0VDLmFzcHhkAgIPFgIeBXN0eWxlBQ1kaXNwbGF5Om5vbmU7ZAIDDxYCHwQFDWRpc';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $login_post); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'c:\var\cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'c:\var\cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);


//echo curl_error($ch);
$content = curl_exec($ch);

//DEBUG
curl_error($ch);

//done initial login screen, close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426528/i-have-tried-to-login-to-facebook-via-curl .You can't re-use a cookie from browser to curl or the opposite but you can try to do the login + page change all in server side like the FB login script.

Comment: If it's like a lot of normal web-based applications (not necessarily websites per se), they will support [HTTP (Digest/Basic) Authentication](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2617), or allow something like OAuth with an auth token to submit in a header.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So essentially, it is impossible to generate a php script that successfully logs in to a website, using curl, whenever you run it -- without manually providing cookie / post information after every time you log out?